# Calculo de Multiplicação em JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso fazer um calculo de porcentagem sobre um valor, porém dependendo do numero a ser calculado *(se houver dizima periodica no resultado por exemplo)* o resultado é arredondado e nao apresenta casas decimais, exemplo:

*(estou calculando por 1.05 porque equivale a um acréscimo de 105%)*

11.114,37 * 1.05 = 11.6697 **(Por que sem casas decimais?)**

11,11     * 1.05 = 11.55   **(O correto seria 11,66)**

Ou seja... O calculo está errado e as vezes nem aparece casas decimais.. 
Preciso dos resultados corretos com apenas 2 casas decimais.
Onde estou errando? Por favor me ajudem!

```html
 <html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
        <form action="" method="">


        
<label for="usuario">  Valor: </label>


<input class="form-control"   name="PO4R_ORCADO" id="PO4R_ORCADO" type="text"   onblur="percentual();" >

                            
<input class="form-control"name="PO4R_MAIS1" id="PO4R_MAIS1" type="text"  >                                
        </form>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function percentual() { 

    var p105 = "1.05";
    var p110 = "1.10";
    var p115 = "1.15";    
    var vl_fr1 = document.getElementById("PO4R_ORCADO").value; //1.114,37
    
 var a1 = parseFloat(vl_fr1)*parseFloat(p105);
 //Multiplica 1.114,37 * 1.05
 
 var a2 = parseFloat(vl_fr1)*parseFloat(p110); 
 var a3 = parseFloat(vl_fr1)*parseFloat(p115);    
 
document.getElementById('PO4R_MAIS1').value = a1; 
// resultado = 11.6697 na calcyladora do windows da 11.670,08

}

</script>
```

RESOLVIDO!!!

Segue a funçao para quem passar pelo mesmo problema que eu!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function percentual() { 
    var p105 = "1.05";
    var p110 = "1.10";
    var p115 = "1.15";    
    var vl_fr1 = document.getElementById("PO4R_ORCADO").value;
    vl_fr1 = vl_fr1.replace(/\./g,'').replace(',', '.');

 var a1 = parseFloat(vl_fr1)*parseFloat(p105);
 var a2 = parseFloat(vl_fr1)*parseFloat(p110); 
 var a3 = parseFloat(vl_fr1)*parseFloat(p115);  
 a1 = a1.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('PO4R_MAIS1').value = a1; 
   }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O parseFloat só irá entender números com a casa decimal separada por '.' ao invés de ','. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Antes de dar o parseFloat, substitua a vírgula digitada no campo por ponto:

```
vl_fr1 = vl_fr1.replace(',', '.');
```

E para pegar apenas duas casas decimais no resultado final, use a função [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), passando o número de casas decimais que deseja.

**EDITADO**

Dessa forma fica mais completo, pois se tiver uma string do tipo '11.111,50', após substituir a vírgula ficará '11.111.50', e o parseFloat também vai dar problema. A solução é substituir a vírgula mas também remover esse segundo ponto:

```
vl_fr1 = vl_fr1.replace(/\./g,'').replace(',', '.');
```

E só então dar o parseFloat. Lembrando que o toFixed arredonda valores, então '11670,0885' com duas casas decimais ficaria '11670,09'.

Comment: Isso é porque nesse caso tem mais de 1 ponto na string, vou editar a resposta para resolver também esse caso.

Comment: Muito obrigado por responder Mais continua sem casas decimais.. dando o replace como sugerido o valor para ser calculado ficou assim (11.114.37) O resultado foi (11.6697) continua sem casas decimais...  continua o mesmo problema :(

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado Voce resolveu meu problema!! Obrigado mesmo

Comment: Show. Se puder, marca a resposta como aceita. Boa sorte.

Answer (score -1):

mais ou menos isso:

```
vl_fr1 = vl_fr1.replace(',', '.');
```